# Meaning of "time in zone"

Tags: bicycling

I am doing a translation into French and I cannot understand the meaning of "**time in zone**". The sentence reads: "It allows you to analyze your **time in zone**, cycling-specific VO2 and recovery time.".

Can anybody explain, please?

Many thanks! 
Lou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are heart rates zones that specific for each person depends on the VO2 max value. As they mention most treadmill boards there are aerobic, anaerobic, cardio, etc... The zone you should analyze is the maximum heart rate(effort) zone that you don't allow lactic acid to decrease your muscle activity. In that zone you can cycle for hours.